# innerHTML not showing html from database

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue where I have an iframe masking a textarea almost like a WYSIWYG scenario. So its all well and good and posts html into the database field. But when I call it back in to the iframe from the databse it does not show? Are there limiters on putting in html into the iframe?

```
<script> 
var iframe = document.getElementById('editor'), 
iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; 
iframedoc.body.innerHTML ="<?php echo ($row[2]); ?>"; // Here is how I retrieve the table content - but does not display inside of the iframe.
</script>
```

If I change it to `innerText` it will just spit out raw html as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an escape function whenever you move data from one language to another.

If you move data from PHP to JavaScript you can use `json_encode`:

```
iframedoc.body.innerHTML = <?php echo json_encode($row[2]); ?>;
```

Imagine if the string is `"; document.location.href="hxxp://naughty.hackers.xxx";"` you're gonna have a problem if you don't escape it.

Comment: and thank you for explaining further for me it makes perfect sense.